# how to improve titlepage. Lines too close to each others

Tags: titles, fontsize, line-spacing, typography

I find the lines are too close to each others in the titlepage I am making.

I am not sure the correct way to fix this. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\begingroup
\fontsize{16pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\textbf{A Solution Manual For}\\
\vspace*{0.5in}
\fontsize{28pt}{22pt}\selectfont
\textbf{Differential equations and the calculus of variations by L. ElSGOLTS. MIR PUBLISHERS, MOSCOW, Third printing 1977.}
\endgroup
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

This is the text

\end{document}
```

Compile with lualatex gives

[image]

I think the problem is caused by increasing the font size for the book name but the default line spacing remains the same as before. May be there is a way to automatically adjust line spacing just for the title corresponding to the new font size?

What is the correct way to change font size and corresponding line spacing at same time?

I'd like a solution that keeps using titlepage as above and not other package or the normal maketitle command for other reasons.

TL 2023

Comment: why are you setting the whole thing as a single paragraph so all with the same (normal) baseline spacing when they are logically distinct and have different font sizes?

Comment: `\fontsize{16pt}{12pt}` means use 16pt font on lines 12pt apart, did you meant to write that???? (the baseline isnot used at all here as you set it as you set it all in a normalsize paragraph with 14pt baseline, but still it looks weird. (and 14pt is still less than 16pt.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know what the correct line spacing should be, that is all. It look like I needed to increase the second argument value, that is all.

Comment: but surely it's clear lines need to be further apart than the size of the letters,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not good in Latex like you are, that is why I asked here for help. I did not know what the correct values should be.

Comment: but that's what I mean, this is nothing to do with latex same would be true if you were using a pen on lined paper, the letters need to be smaller than the space between the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is the distance between lines, so it should be larger. We also use `\par`-like command called `\endgraf`. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\begingroup
%\fontsize{16pt}{12pt}\selectfont % PS
\fontsize{16pt}{20pt}\selectfont % PS
\textbf{A Solution Manual For}\\
\vspace*{0.5in}
%\fontsize{28pt}{22pt}\selectfont % PS
\fontsize{28pt}{34pt}\selectfont % PS
\textbf{Differential equations and the calculus of variations by L. ElSGOLTS. MIR PUBLISHERS, MOSCOW, Third printing 1977.}
\endgraf
\endgroup
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

This is the text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but why endgraf not par, or more simply,a blank line? (or just remove the `\begingroup` `\endgroup` that causes the problem)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my first version `\endgraf` was in the argument of `\textbf`, and `\par` generated errors.